# Question about distribution $F_h=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$

Tags: limits, distribution-theory

How to solve the following:

Let $f:R\rightarrow R$ be a continuous function, $h\in R-\{0\}$ and $F_h:R\rightarrow R$ defined with $F_h=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$. Prove that

a)$F_h\in D'(R)$,

b)$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} F_h=f'$ in $D'(R)$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Who is  $\mathbb{D}(R)$? try to explain the object, beacause notation sometimes don't help!

Comment: $D'(R)$ is notation for distributional space.

Comment: @alans You have to be precise: What is $f'$ if $f$ is just assumed to be continuous. And as a) is completely obvious, where do you see any problems in b), what have you tried?

Comment: @Vobo: $<F_h,\phi>=\int_{R} \frac{f(x)(\phi(x-h)-\phi(x))}{h} dx$, and if we suppose $supp\phi\subset[-M,M]$, then $\phi(x)=\phi(x-h)=0$ for $|x|>M+|h|$. Therefore, integral is finite (f is continuous and bounded, $\phi'$ is bounded). Linearity is easy to check. I proved b) from a), but I am not sure if solution of a) is OK. Did I make any mistake in a)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @mrf: Could you, please, tell me if my solution, that I wrote down in comment (which, by the way, seems complicated) is OK or I made a mistake? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Vobo pointed out, a) is obvious since $F_h$ is continuous (and hence $L^1_{loc}$) for every $h \neq 0$.

For b), let $\phi$ be a test function. Then

\begin{align}
\langle F_h, \phi\rangle &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \phi(x)\,dx \\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{f(x+h)}{h} \phi(x)\,dx - \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{f(x)}{h} \phi(x)\,dx \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{f(x)}{h} \phi(x-h)\,dt - \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{f(x)}{h} \phi(x)\,dx \\
&= -\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \frac{\phi(x)-\phi(x-h)}{h}\,dx \\
&\to -\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \phi'(x)\,dx = \langle f',\phi \rangle
\end{align}
as $h\to 0$, for example by dominated convergence.